r ggpredict log transformed and linear spline
I've hit a roadblock in visualizing the outcome of a model that incorporates both 1) logarithmic transformation of a continuous variable and 2) integrating this transformed variable as a linear spline.
This is a reproducible dataset
Test Data
This is my mixed effects model that includes the linear spline term for log transformed variable
data_df$School_ID  <- as.factor(data_df$School_ID) 
data_df$Student_ID<- as.factor(data_df$Student_ID)

# Fit spline model

ls_m1 <- lme(fixed = Y ~ School_ID + 
               lspline::lspline(log(Arns,2),
                                log(0.058,2)
                                ),
                random = ~1 | Student_ID,
             data = data_df
             
             )


ls_m1

When I try this option
data_df$predict <- predict(ls_m1)

ggplot(data_df, aes(log(Arns,2), predict, color = factor(Student_ID))) +
  geom_line(color = 'black') +
  geom_point(data = data_df, aes(y = Y)) +
  guides(color = guide_none())

I get a plot like this
enter image description here
I was expecting something like this. Any guidance on where I am going wrong is greatly apricated. Thanks
enter image description here

When I try to run your example the lme call fails (Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM): Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1).

@PBulls, PBulls, I have updated the question section with a link where you can download the dataset. Here https://file.io/RFYNebjyioLm hope this solves that error.

@BridgeportBaaS, please update your link to https://fastupload.io/samcGLLJJKLLVWS/file

fastupload is blocked by Chrome. Do you have a "more trustworthy" storage for your data?
